# Unbind project to source control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I have a web API project that is in TFS.

I have a copy of that project somewhere else and i have done some modifications to it for a new project. So I need that project as well to be in TFS.

So when i right-click on solution -> Source control

I don't see "add to source control" Instead it shows these options "Undo , commit , view history .. etc" So it seems like it's linked to TFS to the same old repository.

Also i cannot see source control under file.

How can i fix this?

Comment: maybe it's in local git repo?

Comment: How to fix it in that case?

Comment: it should be other project? just publish it

Answer (score 1):

You have [created a Git repo in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=visual-studio), if you want to sync this project with TFS/DevOps using git version control ([Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops)), you could go the **Settings** page in Team Explorer. Select **Repository Settings**. Under **Remotes**, select **Add**. Enter `origin` in the **Name** field and enter the [clone URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=visual-studio#clone_url) for your repo in the **Fetch** field. Make sure that **Push matches fetch** is checked and select **Save**.

[image]

More details, please refer to the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=visual-studio